# Insert Data from React JS to MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have created a page of feed where I can enter the amount of how many I want to feed. I also have created a MYSQL database table called historyfeed where it has id, amount and date. So on the feed page, I can only enter the amount, the id and date should be automatically assigned every time I enter an amount in the feed page.  The problem now is when I enter an amount, there is no changes at all in my historyfeed database. If I manually insert the data into the table from the phpmyadmin, I can display the data in the other page that I create. Really appreciate for every help.[image] Below is my code.

Code for Feed page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import styles from "./Feed.css";
    import { FaSignOutAlt, FaUserAlt, FaHome } from 'react-icons/fa';
    import { IoSettings } from "react-icons/io5";
    
    export const Feed = () => {
        const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
    
        const handleFeed = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(amount);
        }

        return (
            <div className='background'>
                <button className="logOutButton" ><Link to="/Login"><FaSignOutAlt /></Link></button>
                <button className="profileButton" ><FaUserAlt /></button>
                <button className="settingButton" ><IoSettings /></button>
                <button className="homeButton" ><Link to="/Home"><FaHome /></Link></button>
                <form onSubmit={handleFeed}>
                    <div className='box'>
                            <label htmlFor="amount"><b>Amount</b></label>
                            <input value={amount} onChange={(e) =>     setAmount(e.target.value)}type="amount" placeholder="Please set amount of food" id="amount"     name="amount" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}/>
                            <button>Feed</button>    
                   </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Code to sent the data to mysql database

```
    app.post('/Feed', (req, res) => {
        const amount = req.body.amount;
        const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
      
        const sql = "INSERT INTO historyfeed (Amount, Date) VALUES (?, ?)";
        const values = [amount, date];
      
        db.query(sql, [values],(err,data) => {
        if(err) return res.json("error");
        return res.json(data);
        });
      });
```

I expect to see when I enter the amount in the Feed page, the id and date will be signed automatically while the amount will have the amount that I entered just now.